# Conditions for a decimal to be convertible to binary

Tags: arithmetic, binary

All natural numbers (Base 10) can be converted to binary. No problem. But what about fractional numbers? All cannot be converted (finite expansion).

Example: $0.625$ can be converted but $0.11231$ cannot.

If I were to make a set of all those numbers which can be converted into binary, what condition should I impose on the set of all real numbers? This condition should be able to give an exhaustive list of all such numbers.

Would saying that a number reduced to it's $p/q$ form ($p$ and $q$ being coprime) should contains only powers of $2$ in the denominator be sufficient?

Comment: Are you only allowing finite expansions? That already excludes a lot of rational numbers from having decimal expansions also.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to include finite expansions. I'll add it. Thanks

Comment: In that case, note what happes to the binary if you multiply it by a suitably high power of $2$.

Comment: The number of digits of the binary go high

Comment: But will it become an integer?

Comment: It shouldn't, but I guess finite expansion would make it an integer.

Comment: Well, what happens to the "decimal" point when you multiply by $2$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12483/discussion-between-rva-and-tobias-kildetoft)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The form $p/q$ that you're talking about is called a *binary fraction*, which is any fraction of the form $p/2^k$ where $p$ and $k$ are both integers.